# entity framework sum and average without grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a way in entity framework to get the following simple query

SQL Query

```
select avg(totalsalary), avg(totalhours) from context.employeedetails where company = 1234
```

In entity framework we are doing a group by as in so

```
employeedetails.Where(c => c.company = 1234).GroupBy(c => c.company).Select(x => new 
            {
                avgsalary = x.Average(c => c.totalsalary),
                 = x.Average(c => c.totalhours)
            })
```

Is there a correct way to re-write the above query so we could avoid the unnecessary group by

Answer (score 5):

Is there an issue with using a Group? (which incidentally could just be done as `GroupBy(c => c)`) given you've already used a Where clause to filter.

That said, it cannot (as far as I know) be written in LINQ (without generating two queries instead of one).  If you were happy with two queries, then naturally you could do something like:

```
var query = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.MyVal == 1);

var querySelect = new
{
    aveValue1 = query.Average(x => x.Property1),
    aveValue2 = query.Average(x => x.Property2)
};
```

... but as you would expect, this performs slower.

I therefore recommend you use the query you already have, albeit altering the GroupBy slightly **OR** alternatively you may get slightly better performance by writing it as a Stored Procedure and mapping that SP to your context so you can just say:

```
var query = myContext.MyStoredProcedure(companyId);
```

(for example)!  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes there is an issue when using group since the SQL that is generated is different. I tested it out using LinqPAD and on the DB server it yields inefficient SQL

Comment: @user275157 Hmm, I'll keep an eye on it - thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into use store functions, like these.  These are special stub functions that get translated to in-built store functions at runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx